# Lodash convert array to object

Tags: javascript, lodash

convert array to object the output should be same as key and value.

sample array:(my input structure)

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I need this structure of output:

```
{ 
  '1': 1,
  '2': 2,
  '3': 3,
  '4': 4,
  '5': 5
}
```

Comment: @Li357 uh, `a[0] = 1`, so no the index doesn't correspond to the value

Comment: This structure doesn't seem really useful. While valid, this question might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use lodash's [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#keyBy):

```js
const result = _.keyBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

You don't need a library for that, just a standard [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
let obj = [1,2,3,4,5].reduce((o,k)=>(o[k]=k,o), {})
```

Answer (score 5):

I use reduce here

```js
const listToObject = list => list.reduce((obj, key) => {
          return {
            ...obj,
            [key]:key
          }
        }, {})
        
console.log(listToObject([1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log(
Object.fromEntries(a.map(v => [v, v]))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map objects with same key and value, and assign all to an object.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...array.map(k => ({ [k]: k })));

console.log(result);
```